# How to calculate Wiener index for aromatic and cyclic organic compounds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, cheminformatics

I have been searching for literature on calculating the [Wiener index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_index) for aromatic and cyclic organic compounds. For acyclic aliphatic compounds the methodology is straightforward obtained from obtaining the distance matrix of molecules . However, for aromatic and cyclic compounds is there a general methodology in obtaining the Wiener index?